# convert google form timestamp to day-only date

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

when I save each google form entry in my linkde google sheet, it adds a column with the response's timestamp. What I see in that cell is something like this "17/01/2024 20:55:23". When I print the content of this cell in AppsScript (through console.log()) I get something like this "Wed Jan 17 2024 20:55:22 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)".

What I need is really to be able (in Apps Script) to compare the day in that cell to the current day (new Date()).

So far I haven't managed to do so in Apps Script. Not sure if I should use substrings to manually  extract the interesting part from the sheet's cell (i.e. the day), or if there's a built in function to get the day out of that string?
In google sheet the TO_DATE(INT(A1)) function works wonderfully so ideally I'm looking for something like this to use in Apps Script
Thanks

Comment: `I haven't managed to do so` show what you've tried

Answer (score 0):

To compare the day in a cell with the current day in Google Apps Script, you can use JavaScript's Date object. The date in your Google Sheet is automatically converted to a JavaScript Date object when you retrieve it in Apps Script. Here's the code snippet:

```js
function isSameDay(date1, date2) {
  var d1 = new Date(date1);
  var d2 = new Date(date2);

  return d1.getDate() === d2.getDate() &&
         d1.getMonth() === d2.getMonth() &&
         d1.getFullYear() === d2.getFullYear();
}

function checkDate() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var cellDate = sheet.getRange('A1').getValue(); // Assuming the date is in A1
  var currentDate = new Date();

  var isSameDayResult = isSameDay(cellDate, currentDate);

  console.log("Are the two dates the same day? " + isSameDayResult);
}
```

You need to make sure that both the spreadsheet's (File -> Settings) and Apps Script's (in `appscript.json` that you can enable in Project Settings) timezones are the same. Usually they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Difference in days

```
function compareDates01() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  const dt = new Date();
  const dv = new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate()).valueOf();//current date value 1/17/2024
  const day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;//milliseconds in a day
  const col4 = vs.map(r => {
    let d = new Date(r[0]);
    return [(new Date(d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth(),d.getDate()).valueOf() - dv) / day];//convert timestamp to time at 0:00 hours the beginning of  a day
  });
  col4.unshift(['Diff in Days']);
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(col4).replace(/],/g, '],\n'));//the replace just formats the output to have each row on a different line
  sh.getRange(1, 4, col4.length, col4[0].length).setValues(col4);
}
```

Sheet0 before:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/12/2024 | B2 | C2 |
| 1/13/2024 | B3 | C3 |
| 1/14/2024 | B4 | C4 |
| 1/15/2024 | B5 | C5 |
| 1/16/2024 | B6 | C6 |
| 1/17/2024 | B7 | C7 |
| 1/18/2024 | B8 | C8 |
| 1/19/2024 | B9 | C9 |
| 1/20/2024 | B10 | C10 |
| 1/21/2024 | B11 | C11 |
| 1/22/2024 | B12 | C12 |

Sheet0 after:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | Diff in Days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/12/2024 | B2 | C2 | -5 |
| 1/13/2024 | B3 | C3 | -4 |
| 1/14/2024 | B4 | C4 | -3 |
| 1/15/2024 | B5 | C5 | -2 |
| 1/16/2024 | B6 | C6 | -1 |
| 1/17/2024 | B7 | C7 | 0 |
| 1/18/2024 | B8 | C8 | 1 |
| 1/19/2024 | B9 | C9 | 2 |
| 1/20/2024 | B10 | C10 | 3 |
| 1/21/2024 | B11 | C11 | 4 |
| 1/22/2024 | B12 | C12 | 5 |

```
Execution log
5:56:45 PM  Notice  Execution started
5:56:46 PM  Info    [["Diff in Days"],
[-5],
[-4],
[-3],
[-2],
[-1],
[0],
[1],
[2],
[3],
[4],
[5]]
5:56:47 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

- [Date.valueOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf)
- [Date() constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date)
- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [Utilities.formatDate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format)